# What is the problem with this reactjs setState function code?

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react.js. I am trying to execute a code in VS code based on setState. I have created a button. When I will click on it, the age value will change. But the button is not working. Can you please help me what is the error in the following code?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Pain extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      age: '28'
    }
  }
  changeName(a) {
    this.setState = { age: a }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.age}</h1>
        <button onClick={this.changeName.bind(this, '30')}>Change Name</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Pain
```

Comment: You need to *call* setState, not assign to it. Remove the `=` in `this.setState = ({age: a})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply the wrong syntax in `this.setState`, here's the better code. Another thing could be you should use ES6 arrow function syntax instead of manually using `bind` for better readable.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Pain extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      age: '28'
    }
  }
  changeName = (a) => {
    this.setState({ age: a })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.state.age}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.changeName('30')}>Change Name</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Pain
```

Comment: Can you please tell me when I am running your code its showing me the following error  Line 18:32:  'changeName' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: Edited. I missed `this.` before `changeName`. It should work now. Btw I think you should write React the React Hooks way these days and ages, where you'll never see `this` keyword` again :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class Pain extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()

        this.state = {
            age: "28"
        }
    }

    changeName = age => {
        this.setState({...this.state, age}) 
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.age}</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.changeName("30")}>Change Name</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Pain
```

Comment: There're 2 problems with your code. First you shouldn't use `this.setState({...this.state,})` because the new state will be automatically ***merged*** to the current state if using `setState`, so no need for the rest operator. Second, `onClick={this.changeName("30")}` won't work as expected because you're assigning the return variable of changeName to onClick instead of just the function it self. So it will call `this.setState` every render, which will then lead to rerender => infinite render loop.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out. I already corrected the error in the code. for the setState, Yes, there is no need for the rest operator in this piece of code. but I am assuming state properties will increase over time as the application grows.

Comment: I think it'll be in Redux code, where state is immutable and some more complex thing, then it'll not automatically "merge" to current state. Basically in this situation it merges automatically just because React did it for us, vanilla javascript doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `=` in `setState`.

```
this.setState({age: a})
```